# Can I create a fake eth0 mapped to an existing interface?

Tags: networking

I have a bit of software that is hard coded to open `eth0`. My system assigned the name `enp0s25` to my ethernet connection. I could go through the code and replace all instances of `eth0`; I'm just hoping there is a shortcut I can take.

Is it safe to create symbolic links inside `/sys/class/net`? I see `lo` and `enp0s25` in there. I'm tempted to just create a link named `eth0` there, but I have no idea what that would do to my system.

Answer (score 2):

According to udev manpage the udev-systemd daemon provides interfaces names using internal rules. This can be overriden by adding a rule file in the `/etc/udev/rules.d directory`. One of this file should be used to set persistent ethernet interfaces names, containing commented rules like that one :

```
#SUBSYSTEM=="net", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:1c:c4:e1:2e:d6", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="ethx"
```

You can create your own rule that match your interface MAC address and NAME=eth0.

I recommend you read this : [Understanding systemd’s predictable network device names](https://major.io/2015/08/21/understanding-systemds-predictable-network-device-names/)